# How can i dispatch of Activity completely, so onCreate will be called again

Tags: android

When the activity is destroy i want to release all of its memory so when next
time the user will get to this activity everything will be recreated and onCreate will be called again .
How can i do it?

Comment: onCreate is called after onDestroy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will work API version 19 and above.

```
@Override 
protected void onDestroy() {
super.onDestroy();
 // clear App data
((ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE)).clearApplicationUserData();
 // restart activity here
 activityrestart();
}

public void activityrestart()
{
Intent i = getBaseContext().getPackageManager()
         .getLaunchIntentForPackage( getBaseContext().getPackageName() );
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(i);
}
```

Comment: I need to support API version 19. But eventually I just released all manually. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new intent for your activity and call finish after starting this new instance.

`Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();`

Calling `finish()` on the current activity to make it go through the normal shut down process.